# Python 3.X How to sort this list into descending order as well as justify and hashtag stars

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, justify

How do I obtain this into a sorted list without having count_list return into just 5 returns of nothing, a justified width of 25 to the left and symbols of numbered rank items to = "#"?

after I run the program, it keeps giving me just a list of none's. I'm trying to do a descended list of stars as well as justifying the pibs far from the hashtags at 25 at length.

This is the final output and the further I go into this the further it becomes complex. I also need help on how to attach or append stars to the descending numbers from 5 to 1, I tried doing reverse function but it is not compatible with merely adding the string 'Stars' to it. I believe I may have a solution to assign the stars to the number ranking stars, but I need a solution to check my progress.

Example of printed output:

```
5 Stars:
|# # # # # # #               | #the vertical lines are pibs
4 Stars:
|# #                         |
3 Stars:
|# # # #                     |
2 Stars:
|# #                         |
1 Stars: 
|# # # #                     |
```

This is my own code after some help on it.

```
def count_ratings(st, count_list):
 for i in st:
  if i == "*":
     count_list[0] = count_list[0] + 1
  elif i == "**":
     count_list[1] = count_list[1] + 1
  elif i == "***":
     count_list[2] = count_list[2] + 1
  elif i == "****":
     count_list[3] = count_list[3] + 1  
  else:
     if i == "*****":
        count_list[4] = count_list[4] + 1
 return count_list

def print_ratings():
 ratings = ["*****", "***", "**", "*****", "****", "**", "*", "***","**","*","**","*","*****","****","*****"]
 count_list = [0,0,0,0,0]
 count_list = count_ratings(ratings, count_list)
 for i in count_list:
   print(count_list.sort())


def main(): # defining the main
  print_ratings()
```

Comment: Notice how you have an `if..elif..else` structure where the first branch checks for 1 star and then uses an index of 0, the next branch checks for 2 stars and uses an index of 1, and so on? That's a good indicator that you're violating DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

Comment: I don't understand how your example of the output matches the code. In `ratings`, I see 3 1-star, 4 2-star, 2 3-star, 2 4-star, and 4 5-star, but the output says 4-2-4-2-6.

Comment: that is a different output than before, it is with a different input, but never the less seems correct

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object, which automatically counts each element in your iterable and creates a dictionary. You can then loop over the keys and print an appropriate heading for that star rating, and then the [formatted string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) representing the number of items with that star rating. The `:<23` means an aligned string, left-aligned, filled to a width of 23 characters, with the default fill character (space).

```
from collections import Counter
ratings = ["*****", "***", "**", "*****", "****", "**", "*", "***","**","*","**","*","*****","****","*****"]
c = Counter(ratings)
for k in sorted(c, key=len, reverse=True):
    print(len(k), 'Stars:')
    print('|{:<23}|'.format('# '*c[k]))
```

Result:

```
5 Stars:
|# # # #                |
4 Stars:
|# #                    |
3 Stars:
|# #                    |
2 Stars:
|# # # #                |
1 Stars:
|# # #                  |
```